# How do I sort by minimum with a iterative function?

Tags: python, algorithm, min

My teacher wants me to do an algorithm to sort in ascending order but by using the minimum number in a list and putting it at the beginning. I read a file of numbers and so far I have:

```
  def findMin(ls, n):
        m = 0
        for i in range(1, n):        #n is length
                if ls[i]<ls[m]:
                        m = i
        return m


  def sortlist(ls,n):
        if n == 1:
                return
        m = findMin(ls,n)
        ls.insert(0,m)
        ls.remove(m)
        sortlist(ls, n)
```

I've tried several techniques and can't get it to work. I was trying to put the minimum number at the beginning then minus it from the list so that the function would not count it in the length. I know if I was sorting by maximum I would put n-1 but what do I put for minimum?

Answer (score 1):

From your description what I deduced is that your teacher wants you to implement [Selection Sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). You may want to have a look at it.

In this algorithm, you swap the least number with the current position. Initially the current position is at the beginning of the list and it shifts as you swap values.

Answer (score 0):

This is bubble sort:

```
...
for i in range(0, n-1):
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        if ls[j] < ls[i]:
            temp = ls[i]
            ls[i] = ls[j]
            ls[j] = temp
...
```